# How to define a point by coordinates in QGIS (Plugin)

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I am developing a QGIS plugin and got currently stuck at setting the geometry of a feature based on coordinates.

I retrieve coordinates through an SQL query, create a feature and try to set the geometry.

```
#fetch sql query
rec = dict_cur.fetchone()

#create feature
feature = QgsFeature()
feature.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPoint(QgsPoint(rec[1], rec[2])))
```

In the code above `rec[1]` and `rec[2]` holding the information about longitude and latitude. When requesting the type of `rec[1]` or `rec[2]` it comes back as `<class 'decimal.Decimal'>` and I can cast it to float. However, that doesn't change anything.

When I try to set the coordinates for QgsPoint then I am getting the following error message:

```
feature.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPoint(QgsPoint(rec[1], rec[2])))
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

The error is directely related to QgsPoint. When I seperate QgsPoint and try to provide the coordinates I am getting the same error message.

That is for my plugin. If I use the same code in the Python console of QGIS then it works.

Python is in version 2.7.10
QGIS version is 2.8.2-Wien

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is piece of test code that runs without errors when called normally with `python <filename>`. The imports are the same as the ones that are included by default in the python console embedded into QGIS, as documented [here](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html#python-console).

```
from qgis.core import *
import qgis.utils

# pretend sql record
rec = [0.0, 1.0, 2.0]

#create feature
feature = QgsFeature()
feature.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPoint(QgsPoint(rec[1], rec[2])))
```

The code was tested on python 2.7.6 and QGIS version 2.12.3-Lyon, but I doubt there would have been changes to such a fundamental API between minor versions.

---

The error you are getting is indicative of trying to access something that is set to `None`:

```
>>> None[1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

At least `fetchone()` from python's `sqlite3` package would return (and therefore set `rec` to) `None` if no data was available. Perhaps the connection to the database is behaving differently in the two different environments in which you are testing your code.

---

If the problem persist, it would be helpful if you could edit the question to include the code that initializes the SQL connection and what packages you have imported.

Comment: Thanks for this eye opener! I think I am sitting for too long in front of the screen. Of course, if the query doesn't find something then it returns 'None'. I didn't catch that event, instead pump every return straight into the creation of feature, and continue setting the geometry.